# Is there shallow rendering in Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, jestjs

When testing my Angular app with Jasmine, I have to create mock copies of all components which are used in my target tested component. I am doing it to avoid deep rendering of all included components as I need to render only my 'parent' component.
I wonder is there a shallow render like in React/Jest? Which allows to leave 'real' children of my component, but just stops rendering on 1 level?

Answer (score 0):

[no_errors_schema](https://angular.io/guide/testing#no_errors_schema) seems to be an analogue for shallow rendering of jest/enzyme/react, no that safe though as it skips 'all' errors, not only erros of unrecognized components